# What is the difference between a 63-degree egg and a regular poached egg?

Tags: poaching, eggs

Recently on Master Chef one of the desserts featured a 63-degree egg - what is the difference between that and a regular poached egg?

Answer (score 6):

A 63-degree egg is slow cooked in the shell in a water bath of 63 degrees celsius. The shell is removed after the cooking process. A poached egg is removed from the shell before cooking and cooked in simmering water for a short amount of time. According to [this experiment](http://www.foodiemoment.com/2010/01/21/in-search-of-the-perfectly-cooked-egg-sous-vide-style/), cooking eggs at slightly different temperatures in a water bath seems to make a difference. Perhaps the more exact cooking temperatures of a 63 degree egg give it a different texture than a regular poached egg.

Comment: Yes, also, eggs cooked in their shell at precise temperature are cooked a *lot* longer, often an hour or two. That means that the yolk is cooked to almost exactly the same temperature as the white. You can get yolks that are at various versions of a perfect soft-boiled egg yolk, while the white is not rubbery. They're very different from poached eggs.

Comment: A benefit of the long cooking time at 63 degrees C means the eggs will get pasteurized, whereas regular poached eggs will not get pasteurized. (Of course you can always buy pre-pasteurized eggs if there are safety concerns with poached eggs.)